# numpy array indexing: applying condition over the entire row/col

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this array:

```
a=array([[0. , 0.3, 0.2],
       [0.5, 0. , 0.1]])
```

and this custom min method:

```
def custom_min(l_):
    return min([x for x in l_ if x>0])
```

How do I apply that over the rows to select some of them? For example, if for a row custom_min > 0.1, that row should be selected: i.e.,

```
b = [[0. , 0.3, 0.2]]
```

To be clear, I am looking for methods like this:

```
a[a[:,1] > 0.1]
```

Comment: I'm not understanding - is b your output expected output for custom_min(0.3)?, because the minimum value in that row is `0.1`?

Comment: you are right, i changed the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `numpy.apply_along_axis` to apply `custom_min` to each row.

I'd also rewrite `custom_min` to be more numpythonic: `return min(l_[l_ > 0])`.

Now that you have that custom min in a vector, you can again use logical indexing:

`row_mask = result > 0.3` and `filtered_array = a[row_mask, :]`

EDIT:
Thinking a bit more about how to make everything use only numpy vectorized functions. We can first use `numpy.where` to replace everything smaller than 0 with infinity. That takes it out of consideration for the minimum:

```py
row_wise_custom_mins = np.min(np.where(a > 0, a, np.inf), axis=1)
```

The "where" picks values form `a` if the condition is true and picks `np.inf` if the condition is false. Then we pick the minimum (along axis 1) and that's it.

Comment: `numpy.apply_along_axis` is no faster than using a loop.  It is not a vector function.

Comment: I never claimed it was. I was thinking of having the whole custom minimum computed row-wise, but something like `min(a[a>0], axis=...)` doesn't work because `a[a>0]` creates a flattened array.

Comment: You are correct - OP could use `numpy.amin` with a where condition created using `numpy.less(a, 0.3)`?

Comment: Your comment prompted me to think about being more vectorized, and I've added that new solution I came up with, using `numpy.where` to replace non-positive values with `np.inf`, then just using the standard min.

Comment: Teamwork makes the dreamwork - that's a much more understandable solution than using numpy.less and numpy.amin.  I still don't entirely understand the question.